# ionic - unable to print title on navbar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am working with angular and ionic and i'm currently not able to print ANY title in the navbar.

I have a quite complex setup with multiple nested views.

Here's the list of states:

```
state('app', {
  cache: false,
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: './sections/menu/menu.tpl.html',
  controller: 'menuCtrl'
}).state('app.home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: './sections/menu/pageViewsContainer.tpl.html',
      controller: 'homeCTRL'
    },
    'Details@app.home': {
      templateUrl: './sections/home/home.tpl.html'
    },
    'List@app.home': {
      templateUrl: './sections/List/List.tpl.html'
    }
  }
}).state('app.details', {
  name: 'appDetails',
  url: '/:ID',
  views: {
    'appContent': {
      templateUrl: './sections/menu/pageViewsContainer.tpl.html',
      controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
    },
    'zoneDetails@app.details': {
      templateUrl: './sections/Details/Details/details.tpl.html'
    },
    'zoneList@app.details': {
      templateUrl: './sections/List/List.tpl.html'
    }
  }
});
```

My main (abstract) state is app and uses `menu.tpl.html` which looks like this:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
<ion-side-menu-content class="custom-central-content">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm custom-header-bar">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <!--<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-home" menu-toggle="left"></button>-->
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-home" ui-sref="app.myHouse" id="AppMenuLeftIcon"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right" id="AppMenuRightIcon"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-view ui-view="appContent"></ion-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
           .....
```

inside `<ion-view ui-view="appContent"></ion-view>` I am using the template from `pageViewsContainer.tpl.html` which is:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content class="hg-split-page-container">
        <div ui-view="List" class="hg-split-page-zone-list has-header" nav-transition="none"></div>
        <ion-nav-view name="Details" class="hg-split-page-zone-details"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and then inside both `Details` and `List` I am printing the two views I need.

The problem is that I need to be able to set a static title for the main (home) page, but then dynamically change it when I go inside Details with the name of the page from my scope.

The problem is that I am not able to print ANY title (plain text, not scope) in any way.

I tried with (in pageViewsContainer.tpl.html):

```
<ion-view>

    <ion-nav-title>View 1</ion-nav-title>

    <ion-content class="hg-split-page-container">
        <div ui-view="List" class="hg-split-page-zone-list has-header" nav-transition="none"></div>
        <ion-nav-view name="Details" class="hg-split-page-zone-details"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

---

```
<ion-view view-title="View 1">

        <ion-content class="hg-split-page-container">
            <div ui-view="List" class="hg-split-page-zone-list has-header" nav-transition="none"></div>
            <ion-nav-view name="Details" class="hg-split-page-zone-details"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

---

as well as (inside details template):

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>View 1</ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content class="has-footer has-header">
     ...
```

---

```
<ion-view view-title="View 1">
        <ion-content class="has-footer has-header">
         ...
```

But nothing worked.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to change quite a bit on my navigation, as I was using the nested views, parent, childs in a completely wrong way. It's working fine now.

Also, if, for some reasons, the title navbar it's still not displayed, you can force it using this in the controller (coffeescript):

```
# This should show the navabar everytime the view is entered
$scope.$on '$ionicView.enter', () ->
  $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the title command inside header-bar

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">View 1</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
<ion-view>
```

or try

```
<ion-view>
  <div class="bar bar-header browse-header" align-title="center">
    <h1 class="title">View 1</h1>
 </div>
 <ion-content class="has-header">
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't really work. I already have a navbar common to all the apges and ideally I need to be able to use the ion-nav-title directive to print the title in the navbar for each specific page.

Comment: Try using a variable in app.js which is your abstract controller. Add that variable in inside your ion-nav bar. In your child views, keep updating the variable when the child controller is loaded.

Comment: For the time being, untill I find out why ion-nav-title is not working, I am using $ionicNavBarDelegate.title to display it on every state changes